# The service "sonata.block.service.container" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I use from SonataAdminBundle when installed this bundle by composer show this error:

```
The service "sonata.block.service.container" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating".
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure twig is installed and available in your configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

Source: [Stack Overflow #47656816](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656816/you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-templating)

Comment: It's not clear from this snippet, but "templating" should be a child of "framework"

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake, I've just edited it