# Symfony4 - 'app/config/config.yml' is missing?

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, doctrine

I am new with Symfony4, and creating Login Form with [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html). And I got stuck at step 5 mentioned in this article. When it says:

> Add the following configuration to your config.yml file according to
>   which type of datastore you are using.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

The problem is that in symfony4, there is no `app` folder, and no simple `config.yml` file in config folder.

I think this article might be working with older versions, but for Symfony4, it may need some amendments.

Can any body suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not to create it `config/packages/fos.yaml` ?
Or add in one of existing `config/packages/foo.yaml` ?
`https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html`

Comment: Can you tell me which exact file should I update, as per the mentioned article.

Comment: create new `config/packages/fos_user.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

for that problem you can try this:

Create `fos_user.yaml` file under `config/packages` folder then you can add the configuration code as usual, symfony4 will load it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As Arnold Richmon indicated. Also, in the fos_user.yaml file you need to add config options as:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\YourUserEntityClass
    from_email:
        address: "youremail@yourdomain.whatever"
        sender_name: "yoursendername"
```

Answer (score 2):

to complete with [service:mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641679/the-service-fos-user-mailer-has-a-dependency-on-a-non-existent-service-templa) and resume, create:

*config/packages/fos_user.yaml*

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\YourUserEntityClass
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
        address: "youremail@yourdomain.whatever"
        sender_name: "yoursendername"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 4 ,the new config/ directory is the equivalent of the current app/config/ directory but with a very different layout.

Check this link for more details:  https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-a-new-way-to-develop-applications

Comment: Yes right. But I could not understand how to update config(which file, there are many files in config folder) around symfony4 from that article.

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844967/symfony-4-fosuserbundle